# Why Request in IOS return sucess false( unknown error)?

Tags: ios, json, unity-game-engine, request

I make a request to the server asking for login, which takes my mail, password and a firebase token, all of these are sent correctly, however, the response data returns with a false and an unkwown error, this happens only on Ios

Already checked the petition on Insomnia, read various of the jsons returned and reduced the problem to Ios platform, checked the pod file to see if I missed references, but it all seems right

```
void generatePOSTRequest(string slug, string request, System.Action<string> callback)
    {
        WWW www;
        Dictionary<string,string> postHeader = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        postHeader.Add("Method", "POST");
        postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        byte[] formData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
        www = new WWW(apiURL + slug, formData,postHeader);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www,callback));
    }
```

//slug is server/api/login
//request is a json with a mail, a password and the firebase token

Comment: what version of unity are you on? www is depreciated, so, while that may not be the final answer, it might not help either

Comment: hi bugFinder, the version of unity is 2019.2.0a9.

Comment: then yes, you should have moved about 18 months ago to unityhttprequest

Comment: well, that is a huge redo to make, everything else in the app works with www and doesn't give me this problem

Comment: Well.. part of me wants to say they depreciated it back in 2018 if not earlier.. so cant help that you havent noticed that.  I thought it gave warnings on compile time for it.. I know it certainly does if you import assets with www..    In fact its marked obsolete not even depreciated..   the fact you are using the alpha also wont help as the alpha almost comes with a disclaimer of "if it didnt eat your children be impressed".. they were going to remove www, so, while it works in some places, go you, but you should have moved. for the error check the return text